# Playwright - How to access Event Listeners stored data using Javascript?

Tags: typescript, canvas, event-listener, playwright, eventhandler

I'm currently writing an e2e test case using Playwright with TypeScript. I want to get the data stored in Chartjs canvas. I found it's stored in the element's event listener handler and tried to access with the code below, however only getting `{ event: { isTrusted: false } }` as result.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
const eventData = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function captureEvent(event) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", captureEvent);

        resolve({
          event: event
        });
      });

      const event = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
        clientX: 100,
        clientY: 100,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      });
      canvas.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
  });

  console.log(eventData);
```

And here is the handler I'm trying to access, I found it in browser inspect's element event listeners:
[image]

Wonder is there any possible way to achieve what I'm trying to do, thank you!

Comment: You could try by building your own object instead of returning the `event`. You might have a serialization issue.

Comment: @hardkoded It's okay for me to access items like ClientX and ClientY from MouseEvent, however I couldn't find ways to access the handler

Comment: It seems the handler is a function. You won't be able to send the handler back to the node side.